# Issues with scope in listener methods

Tags: c#

I want to be able to reference the `Reaction` object of the `EquationClass` class from all of the methods in this `CalculatorPage` class. I declared the `Reaction` object in the first event listener method. The second event listener however can't access the instance of the class and I'm not sure how to fix it.

I tried changing the first method to `public` but the error persisted.

```cs
private void ExampleListenerMethodOne(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var Reaction = new EquationClass("Example");
    Reaction.species = Reaction.MakeAndReturnSpeciesArray();
}

public void ExampleListenerMethodTwo(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Reaction.species); //Here is the 'Does not exist 
                                         //in current context error'
}
```

I would expect to be able to access the object from anywhere but I can't.
I get a *"does not exist in current context error"* from visual studio. I have read the other questions that are related but I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: You could make a property of type Reaction and whenever the place that needs it gets instantiated, just reference the name of the property.

Comment: In your first method you have `var Reaction = ...`. The `Reaction` variable is local to the method and goes out of scope when the method ends. The second method knows nothing of the local variables of the first method

Comment: You might consider re-reading your question and thinking "what would someone who doesn't know everything I do about my code understand from what I'm saying". In particular you should copy/paste the exact error message, mention whether it's a compile or run time error and point to the line it occurs in. You might also want to tag the with `[wpf]`

Comment: There are many ways to address the issue. See marked duplicate for one approach. Consider using Stack Overflow's search feature to find similar questions, with other approaches. What's best in your case will depend on the broader context, which you haven't provided. For all we know, you have other mistakes in your code; for example, maybe you shouldn't even be creating a new instance of `EquationClass` in the first method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just turn it to a property.  Here the class instantiates a new variable of type Reaction (with whatever you need to do to do it).  Therefore, the myReaction variable is in a class level scope to the two methods below that need it.  Previously, your variable was in a method scope meaning it can't be used outside of the method.  There is also a block scope for variables defined in a code block such as if statements with a variable defined within the if statement.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public Reaction myReaction { get; set; }

    public MyClass()
    {
        myReaction = new EquationClass("Example");
    }

    private void ExampleListenerMethodOne(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myReaction.species = Reaction.MakeAndReturnSpeciesArray();
    }

   public void ExampleListenerMethodTwo(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(Reaction.species);
   }
}
```